# Reset BIOS password for toshiba satellite L635-S30128N?

Tags: bios, passwords, toshiba-laptop

I have laptop computer.

toshiba satellite L635-S30128N
PART NO. PSKOOU-01V002
SERIAL NO. 7A613289Q
I leave it since 6 months. now when I try turn on show on monitor (enter the password),
I tried removing the battery for 24 hours without a result.
What is the solution

Comment: Bios password?.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're comfortable opening your laptop up.

First remove any power and the main battery from your laptop.

Then you have to open the laptop up and remove the CMOS battery. It'll probably be a CR2032 button style battery similar to this:

[image: CMOS Battery]

Leave it out for a few minutes before putting it all back together.

Comment: I was remove the battery for 24 hours but my laptop did not work.

Comment: The battery in my answer? If that's the case, then there's likely a jumper that you will need to find. It's also possible that the password is stored in non-volatile ROM - in that case there may not be anything you can do without talking to Toshiba Support directly.